# Protection for executables in Windows-10

Tags: windows-10, security

I want to protect exe, dll from unintentional/accidental modifications. Assumption is that there is no anvtivirus on background but the LAN/environment is cyber-protected from outside. How can I combine Windows-10 System-Restore and Windows-10 Security to make some folder/exe/dll to be more protected?

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you are trying to accomplish and/or who.what you are trying to protect from?

Comment: If you manage to do that (for whatever reason) any software update to those files will start failing.

Comment: @DavidPostill That's ok. Those files are not supposed to be updated automatically.

Comment: @Keltari There are some regulations basically saying "Executable must be protected from accidental/unintentional/intentional modifications. Even through it runs in internal LAN protected by firewall. On other hand AV is not possible by performance/RT issues.

Comment: Ordinary users cannot delete properly installed executables. There is no point to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the advanced NTFS file system settings to allow only reading of the files.  You can disable deleting, renaming modifying, etc.  However, this can break things down the line like updates and other modifications.  You will have to reverse the process to allow any changes.

Read more [here](http://ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-file-advanced.htm).